# How to format date correctly in LUA script - 05292020

Tags: lua

I'm having some difficulty formatting the date in this LUA script. I want it to output the current date in the following format - **05292020**. However, I can't get the year to format correctly, so my output is **052920**. I've been searching extensively to find a solution but I'm really stuck on this one. Anyone able to point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance!

```
function OnEvent(event, arg, family)
  if event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then


    -- Take the first 8 characters only (1,8)
    local date = string.sub(GetDate(), 1, 8)
    for i = 1, #date do
      local ch = date:sub(i,i)
      if ch == "-" then
        PressAndReleaseKey("minus")
      elseif ch == "," then
        PressAndReleaseKey("comma")
      elseif ch == "." then
        PressAndReleaseKey("period")
      elseif ch == "/" then
      --  PressAndReleaseKey("slash")
      elseif ch == " " then
        PressAndReleaseKey("spacebar")
      elseif ch == ":" then
        PressKey("lshift")
        Sleep(10)
        PressAndReleaseKey("semicolon")
        ReleaseKey("lshift")
      elseif ch == ch:lower() then
        PressAndReleaseKey(ch)
      else
        PressKey("lshift")
        Sleep(10)
        PressAndReleaseKey(ch:lower())
        ReleaseKey("lshift")
      end
    end


  end
end
```

Comment: Try `os.date("%m%d%Y")`.

Comment: Where should I insert that though? This is the first time I've worked with LUA scripting so I'm not very familiar with the syntax.

Comment: Insert it instead of `string.sub(GetDate(), 1, 8)` in your code

Comment: I tried inserting ```os.date("%m%d%Y")``` into ```string.sub(GetDate(), 1, 8)``` but i'm getting the following error:[string "LuaVM"]:10:attempt to index global 'os' (a nil value)

Answer (score 0):

For my needs I do it this way:

```
-- CURRENT DATE AND TIME
local myyear = os.date("*t").year
local mymonth = os.date("*t").month; if mymonth < 10 then mymonth = "0"..mymonth end
local myday = os.date("*t").day; if myday < 10 then myday = "0"..myday end
local myhour = os.date("*t").hour; if myhour < 10 then myhour = "0"..myhour end
local mymin = os.date("*t").min; if mymin < 10 then mymin = "0"..mymin end
local mysec = os.date("*t").sec; if mysec < 10 then mysec = "0"..mysec end
local mytime = myyear..mymonth..myday.."_"..myhour..mymin..mysec
print(mytime)
```

Hope this is not too complicated and can be of help?

PS: I am using gideros engine which uses lua.

Comment: `os.date` accepts formats to handle all this. `os.date("%Y%m%d_%T")` gives your format.

Comment: Hi Mourad! I keep getting this error when running the code: [string "LuaVM"]:4:attempt to index global 'os' . Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: sorry I don't know, have to tried the other answers and do you have the same error? Maybe your version of lua? You need to try to make it work with a very simple example and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a matter to use the correct format with `os.date`, something like:

```
print(os.date("%d%m%Y"))
```

Comment: You mean `os.date("%m%d%Y")`